# auto resize JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, autoresize

Is there any way to autoresize a JTabbedPane to the same size that the JFrame has?
I'm using netbeans to create the swing interface and I can't figure out whether this is a property that I can set through the GUI designer or if I have to do it programmatically. If I need to do it programatically, netbeans doesn't allow users to modify the auto generated UI code.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: This is the job of the container LayoutManager. I have never used NetBeans so I can't help you on how to do it with NetBeans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) should be useful for understanding how components are arranged in container.
For your task I would use BorderLayout and placed the JTabbedPane into it's center area.
For example:

```
 frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 frame.getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

In netbeans you just change your frame layout to BorderLayout and after that in properties for the JTabbedPane set layout constraint CENTER